# Autocomplete development environment of pygobject in Windows10

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, pygobject, msys2

I am looking for an environment where pygobject can autocomplete.
Is it possible with VSCode or one of the IDEs?

While constructing the environment with MSYS2 while looking at the following.
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

I tried using VSCode.
However, I found that autocomplete can not be used for the following reasons.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/582

I want to develop it with VSCode.
Or want to develop with either IDE.

I look forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but I found instruction for doing this with [Wing](https://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/pygobject).

In short, it says to use a tool called [fakegir](https://github.com/strycore/fakegir), which

> is a tool to build a fake Python package of PyGObject modules...

The fakegir page also has instructions for integration with [VS Code](https://github.com/strycore/fakegir#vs-code-support) (which I haven't tried either).

Unfortunately, fakegir seems to assume a *nix file structure, but hopefully it will work on Windows with adjustments to the default paths.

Comment: And if you do manage to get it working, may I suggest that you make a pull request to the project so they can support other Windows users (or if you don't know how to get it working, open an issue and request that they add that support).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with linux VScode by installing stubs as below :

```
$ pip install PyGObject-stubs
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73452542/8067360)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34530878)