# code completion support with gi.repository in VS Code

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

I'm trying do code a simple app with GTK4 in Python using VS Code.

What I do:

```py
gi.require_version("Gtk", "4.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

I don't have any auto completion or type hints in my IDE because gi.repository uses dynamic imports, is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python typing annotations can be written separately from the main module code (in `.pyi` files or as a stubs module).

Run `$ pip install PyGObject-stubs` to install 3d-party type annotations and reload VS Code window